# Anonymizing and masking of text data

Tags: text-mining, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have a set of emails which i need to anonymize before I can do any analysis on it. Since sensitive data may be disclosed in the emails, like referring to people, or providing phonenumbers etc.

The tools i have found so far, only uses tables, and mask this, which is quite straight forward to do myself, but it does not solve my problem.

So i am looking for a tool or library, that can help me solve this. I would assume it need to do some Natural language processing in order to analyze how the text is built up, and where refferences to people are being mentioned. I would also appreciate any good articles in this area

Comment: If anyone wondered, i found that Google has an NLP Rest api, which can be used for this purpose (https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/). However it only has nlp models for English, Spanish and Japanese for the moment

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem like yours. I have an NLP background. But I cannot see how a straightforward solution can be found in the google cloud page. Can you tell me more?